# Как извлечь данные html элемента с помощью PHP?

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Например, есть элемент textarea, пользователь туда вводит какое-нибудь сообщение, и с помощью PHP нужно записать эти данные в переменную, чтобы передать далее в базу данных. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: почитайте http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.external.php

Answer (score 0):

Создайте форму, а потом принимайте с помощью поста.

Html:

```
<form action="action-url.php" method="post">
     <textarea name="text"></textarea>
     <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
    // код обработки
}
?>
```

Comment: Кроме GET/POST какие варианты есть? Я вижу в этом способе некоторые недостатки.

Comment: Только если использовать AJAX

Comment: @Степан а аякс не get-post использует что ли? :)

Comment: @EugeneJohnson какие могут быть недостатки в `GET`/`POST` если это основные два запроса HTTP-протокола? "Способ" это оправка через форму, а тип запроса это средство. Дак в чем вы видите недостатки, в форме или в типе запроса? GET, кстати, для изменения данных обычно не используется, что даже следует из его названия.

Comment: @teran аж по коже мурашки пошли, до слёз пробрало))

Comment: @teran можно еще сокеты попробовать))